# Can't install Docker on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, ubuntu

I am trying to install Docker on my Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.3.0-40-generic x86_64)

Following the instructions, I am doing the following and getting an error, please advise how to solve it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 11, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 67, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gio
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import _gi
ImportError: cannot import name '_gi' from 'gi' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py)
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/880188/gnome-terminal-will-not-start

Comment: Are you going to install Docker Community Edition? This is the docs https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/

Comment: @Tuan yes, finally solved and posted the solution

Comment: Try out these steps https://grizzlybit.info/2020-04-11-install-docker-on-ubuntu-18/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While trying to install docker on my Ubuntu 18.04.4 EC2 I have encountered with the following error when trying [Docker Install Guide](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/)
4th step:

```
sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
```

I have got errors like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/update-manager", line 28, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gtk
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 27, in <module> from ._gi import _API
ImportError: No module named 'gi._gi'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 64, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 20, in <module>
import apt
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
import apt_pkg
ImportError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/update-manager", line 28, in <module>
from gi.repository import Gtk
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
from ._gi import _API
ImportError: No module named 'gi._gi'
```

I have solved it with the following copy .io files:

For apt_pkg:

```
cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
sudo cp apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
Basically, if you get a No such file or directory just ls to try to get the right name.
```

For gi:

```
sudo cp _gi.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so _gi.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

sudo cp _gi_cairo.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so _gi_cairo.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

And everything started to work.